# Microsoft Office: math

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have to give a presentation to my classmates in a couple of days, and I have Microsoft Office Powerpoint 2003 to my disposal. Is there some of way to put equations in my powerpoint (any equation I want) and also gifs?

My presentation is on taylor series so you can see why math is essential, and gifs are handy.

Comment: I found the answer to this question in approximately twenty seconds using google, I do not understand why you had to post the question here. -1

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [we actually expect you to do a little research before asking](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask), and failure to do so just invites down votes by other members of the community. It's actually rather nice of @ChickenP to explain why he down voted, otherwise you'd have the negative score and no idea why.

Comment: Aniel, why did you remove my comment? I do not appreciate you removing my comment Aniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**equations**

From: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/insert-an-equation-HP005194680.aspx

To insert an equation in a presentation, use the characters and commands that are available in Microsoft Equation Editor.

1. Click the slide to which you want to add an equation.
2. On the Insert menu, click Object.
3. In the Object type list, click Microsoft Equation 3.0. If Microsoft Equation 3.0 is not available, install it.
4. In the Equation Editor, use the buttons and menus to type your equation.
5. To return to Microsoft PowerPoint, on the File menu in Equation Editor, click Exit and Return to .

The equation appears on your slide.

**animated gif**

As long as the iterations are > 0 they should be played otherwise change the iteration to a value > 0